# How to read csv file data line by line in Azure Data Factory and store it in a variable

Tags: csv, azure-data-factory

I want to read a csv file line by line and store that value in variable so that i can pass that in for each activity in Azure data factory.

So I want to read records line by line and store each record in a variable so that we can pass in for each activity one by one  and generate new data based on these records.

How can we achive this ?

Comment: Hi @shivam, welcome to StackOverflow. If you could outline what you are trying to accomplish (the end result), it could help inform the answer.

Comment: @Joel Actually, I want to use the records of the file as an Input in some other activity that's why I am using for each activity in order to pass the value one by one

Comment: Hi @SHIVAMYADAV ,If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any other concerns? If you never accept others answer, community members won't help you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. Lookup active to get the data of the csv data.
   [image]
2. Foreach the csv rows.
   [image]
3. In Foreach active, set the row value to the variable.
   [image]
4. Build your active after the variable, for example:
   [image]

If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know.

HTH.

Comment: how to copy the data of set variable to file  using copy data activity. I tried by using a blank file as a data source and make a column having value of set variable. But this didn’t work

Comment: Do you mean you use add column in copy active source settings to receive the data of the set variable and it doesn't work?

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV then what's the error? It's not caused by the source that means the set variable should works.

Comment: @SHIVAMYADAV do you have any other concerns? Can you please accept it is as answer?